# Do we need to restart all processes when I increase IOPS for a AWS volume

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, amazon-ebs

I recently increased IOPS for a commit log, now should I restart cassandra process to get IOPS in action? I don't find it docs.
Please let me know if you come across anywhere in docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the IOPS is modified on a Provision IOPS Elastic Block Store (EBS) Volume, resources are reprovisioned automatically.

It will take time to adjust the IOPS of the volume -- progress can be monitored via the management console.

Once the volume modification is complete, the volume will operate with a higher IOPS. There is no need to restart an application since the modification is transparent. It will simply operate faster if more requests are sent to the volume.

Comment: Thanks John, Can you point me some reference links from aws documentation please? ( Actually I'm still  seeing lot of dropped mutations.)

Comment: See: Modifying the Size, IOPS, or Type of an EBS Volume on Linux](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-modify-volume.html). Please note that a higher EBS IOPS setting does not guarantee faster disk access -- much of it depends on how the application is using the disk (eg queuing IO so the full speed is utilized).